# How to add config args to postgres service container in Github Action?

Tags: postgresql, docker, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am using Github Actions Service Container to start a postgres instance like so:

```
name: Pull Request

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - staging

jobs:
  test-and-build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      redis:
        image: redis
        ports:
          - 6379:6379
      postgres:
        image: postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
        ports:
          - 5432:5432

...
```

This works but I would like to speedup the postgres instance by disabling fsync as described here: https://dev.to/thejessleigh/speed-up-your-postgresql-unit-tests-with-one-weird-trick-364p

When running postgres locally in a docker container this speeds up my run massively, im hoping to do the same in Github Actions but am struggling to see how I configure the image. It appears that passing `-c fsync=off` into the options block above causes an error:

```
Exit code 125 returned from process: file name '/usr/bin/docker', arguments 'create --name 04a7236d2e964fccb8a7d95684b3cf05_postgres_0249b3 --label cc4956 --network github_network_3023184aafab424896b4e553d7ad9c38 --network-alias postgres -p 5432:5432 --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 5 -c fsync=off -e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true postgres'.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way to inject commands into services currently so that you can turn off the rsync feature. Github actions uses create command which does not support the `-c` attribute.

But you could use a different image from `https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql` which allows you to turn it off through an env variable. Here is an example:

```
name: Postgress test
on:
  push:
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      postgres:
        image: 'bitnami/postgresql:latest'
        env:
          POSTGRESQL_DATABASE: test_postgress
          POSTGRESQL_USERNAME: test_user
          POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD: test_password
          POSTGRESQL_FSYNC: "off"
        options: >-
          --health-cmd "pg_isready -d test_postgress -U test_user -p 5432"
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
    steps:
      - run: echo test
```

Side note, this env is not documented in their readme, but you can find it in their source code
https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql/blob/b2b1c1410293fc9a8b58a52b56f2ceabdac59bb1/9.6/debian-10/rootfs/opt/bitnami/scripts/libpostgresql.sh#L433-L445

Comment: Awesome! This pretty much half's the time to run my tests, massive props, thanks :)

Comment: Glad to hear it 

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure when this was added, but you can use POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS to supply any [args allowed for initdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html):

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    env:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: --no-sync
    options: >-
      --health-cmd pg_isready
      --health-interval 10s
      --health-timeout 5s
      --health-retries 5
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Comment: I tried adding this env var, however my tests didn't experience any noticeable improvements.

Comment: We only saw a ~10% improvement iirc, but it really depends on how many write operations you do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to create your own dockerfile you can run a bash script to make any config changes you like. You can also execute sql commands in the same manner.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres

COPY docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

RUN ["chmod", "-R", "+x", "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/"]
```

Example file in `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo -e '\nfsync = off' >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

In your docker compose, simply replace `image: postgres` with `build:` pointing to this dockerfile.